Docker: always bind mount a volume to each container
I want to mount /etc/localtime and /etc/ssl/certs into each container I start up with docker run, without passing -v each time. Is this possible? I know that daemon.json doesn't have an option to define mounts, but a simple "append -v <src>:<dest>:ro to each docker run command" would suffice for me.
Is there any way I could do that?
Found nothing on either https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon or https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/dockerd/#on-linux

There's no option like that.  (This could be a major security concern if the system was configured to silently replace files in containers' /etc directories like you suggest.)

You could place a proxy in front of /run/docker.sock that intercepts container create API calls and adds your desired arguments. This wouldn't be tremendously difficult (for the most part it's just an HTTP API with JSON content), but you would probably need to write it yourself.

Thanks guys. To mitigate the security concerns, I would of course mount them read-only (edited my question accordingly). I'll look up socket interception, thanks.

Simplest thing would be to create a bash function that will add those parameters to whatever else you supply.

True, but I want to make the daemon aware of it such that no matter how the containers are started (docker run/start, docker compose up/start, direct communication with the docker daemon through socket), I want to mount those volumes.
